# PostgreSQL: работа с датой

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть запрос:

```
select * from people
where date_birthday between '1982-01-10' and '1987-01-10';
```

Встал вопрос как его модифицировать и сделать универсальным если дата будет в формате `dd-mm-yyyy`, пытаюсь сделать через функцию `to_char`, т.е.:

```
select * from people
where date_birthday
between 
(to_char(date_birthday ,'DD-MM-YYYY') = '1982-01-10') 
and 
(to_char(date_birthday ,'DD-MM-YYYY') = '1987-01-10');
```

Но в результате получаю пустой набор. В чем моя ошибка и какую лучше функцию для работы с датой в данной ситуации нужно использовать?

Answer (score 1):

Лучше переведите текст в таймстампы, так как сравнение строк медленнее,
будет производиться для **каждой** даты в таблице, и зависит от
локали:

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM people
 WHERE date_birthday
       BETWEEN to_timestamp('10-01-1982', 'DD-MM-YYYY')
           AND to_timestamp('10-01-1987', 'DD-MM-YYYY')
;
```